# How do you get more flags?

Tags: support

So, I flagged a comment for being unuseful, and it now says I have nine flags left. So I was wondering, how do I get more? I do not intend on flagging posts willy-nilly, but I was just curious.

Comment: related: http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/11425/i-got-more-flags-day-is-that-because-of-the-marshal-badge